# LessCSS : argb() not working on variable with dynamic name

Tags: variables, dynamic, colors, escaping, less

I created a mixin, that uses the argb() method (for IE filter gradient)
This mixin takes a parameter, used to set the good variable name to pick among a list of variables. These variables store hexa colors.

```
@var_foo: #FFFFFF;
@var_bar: #000000;

.setColor(@colorName){
    @colorVar: ~'@{var_@{colorName}}';
    @colorArgb: argb(@colorVar);
}
```

This cause me the error : 
error evaluating function `argb`: Object # has no method 'toARGB'

It seems it doesn't like the escape function. When I replace the @colorVar directly with an hardcoded @var_foo, it works.
Am I doing something wrong, or the argb() method needs something special ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the constructed variable name wrongly.

You should use the `@@` to call a [variable from a variable name](http://lesscss.org/#-variables).

**LESS:**

```
@var_foo: #FFFFFF;
@var_bar: #000000;

.setColor(@colorName) {
    @colorVar: 'var_@{colorName}';
    @colorArgb: argb(@@colorVar);
    color: @colorArgb;
}

.setColor(bar);
```

will return this **CSS:**

```
color: #ff000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin's answer as far as it goes, but it appears to me that you want two variables set with color properties, and his solution leaves the main color variable as a string. Therefore, I recommend setting an initial getter variable to then use to set the two color variables. Here is an example (not knowing how you are using the colors, I'm just putting something together here--it is unlikely you would be using the IE format argb for `background-color`, but you get the idea):

**LESS**

```
@var_foo: #FFFFFF;
@var_bar: #000000;

.setColor(@colorName) {
  @getColor: 'var_@{colorName}';
  @colorVar: @@getColor;
  @colorArgb: argb(@@getColor);
}

.test {
  .setColor(foo);
  color: @colorVar;
  background-color: @colorArgb;
}

.test2 {
  .setColor(bar);
  color: @colorVar;
  background-color: @colorArgb;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffffff;
}
.test2 {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ff000000;
}
```

Comment: You have a point, I used `@colorVar` to hold the variable name (as the getter variable). I just didn't think there was a need for defining another variable that holds the original color, as you can get the color directly from variables `@var_foo` and `@var_bar` by calling `@@colorVar`, and of course you can use it now in any other variables and color operations, depends on what exactly you want to use them for ^_^